# embedFonts when applied, dynamic text doesn't appear (must need it for FlashEff2)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I don't understand, what is wrong with this simple peice of code: (FlashCS4, AS3)

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "Arial Black", 16, 0, false );
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.text = "Hello"; //set text last
addChild(tf);
```

It doesn't create or show anything, and if i comment this line `tf.embedFonts = true;` then it works fine.

My motive is to change the font realtime, whenever user select a different font, the dynamic text field should change accordingly.

I have applied TextEff2 for some animation, and it must need `embedFonts` set to `true`.

Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: did you embed the font in the library?

Comment: ok, i just did it worked. But how can i do it without adding font into library? OR can i do this via actionscript? Because it needs to load fonts used in the user system where swf is playing.

Comment: i believe you always have to embed them into the swf, maybe there is a workaround if it would increase your file size substantially